# Document-Term-Matrix of tm Package in R

Tags: r, matrix, document, tm

I am using document term matrix of tm package in R. I faced an error saying:

```
Doc <- DocumentTermMatrix(Data)
Error in UseMethod("TermDocumentMatrix", x) : 

no applicable method for 'TermDocumentMatrix' applied to an object of class "table"
```

I tried data frame, data table, matrix and table but I faced the error again and again. Could you please tell me what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a step... you have to create a "corpus" first...

```
library("tm")
txt <- c("some text", "here in this", "vector as an example")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(txt))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
```